# Algorithm for finding trends in data?

Tags: java, algorithm, analytics, bigdata

I'm looking for an algorithm that is able to find trends in large amounts of data. For instance, if one is given time `t` and a variable `x`, `(t,x)`, and given input such as `{(1,1), (2,4), (3,9), (4,16)}`, it should be able to figure out that the value of `x` for `t=5` is 25. How is this normally implemented? Do most algorithms compute lines of best fit that are linear, quadratic, exponential, etc. and then chooses the line of best fit with the lowest standard deviation? Are there other techniques for finding trends in data? Also, what happens when you increase the number of variables to analyze large vectors?

Comment: Entire departments in companies are created to find that perfect algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really complex question, try to start from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: Is there a method of this that is more accurate at predicting data points that are outside of the previous data points, such as the example of things based on time and predicting the future?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation
But predicted values are obviously less accurate than interpolation process...

Comment: I would be much clearer but this question is really broad. In computer science academy there are courses six-months long just for this issues...

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer for a complex problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Answer (score 0):

A [Neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network) might be a good candidate. Especially if you want to learn it something nonlinear.