# How to find trend (growth/decrease/stationarity) of a data series

Tags: algorithm, analysis, trend

I am trying to extract the [OEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overall_equipment_effectiveness) trend of a manufacturing machine. I already have a dataset of OEE calculated more or less every 30 seconds for each manufacturing machine and stored in a database.

What I want to do is to extract a subset of the dataset (say, last 30 minutes) and state if the OEE has grown, decreased or has been stable (withing a certain threshold). My task is NOT to forecast what will be the next value of OEE, but just to know if has decreased (*desired return value: -1*), grown (*desired return value: +1*) or been stable (*desired return value: 0*) based on the dataset. I am using `Java 8` in my project.

Here is an example of dataset:

```
71.37
71.37
70.91
70.30
70.30
70.42
70.42
69.77
69.77
69.29
68.92
68.92
68.61
68.61
68.91
68.91
68.50
68.71
69.27
69.26
69.89
69.85
69.98
69.93
69.39
68.97
69.03
```

From this dataset is possible to state that the OEE has been decreasing (of couse based on a threshold), thus the algorithm would return -1.

I have been searching on the web unsuccessfully. I have found [this](https://geekprompt.github.io/Java-implementation-for-Double-Exponential-Smoothing-for-time-series-with-linear-trend/), or [this github project](https://github.com/Workday/timeseries-forecast), or [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032717/algorithm-for-finding-trends-in-data). However, all those are (more or less) complex forecasting algorithm. I am searching for a much easier solution. Any help is apreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by a much easier solution? I can think of a very easy solution - compare the first and last value (and see if the difference exceeds a threshold).

Comment: Comparing the first and the last value is not a suitable solution because it does not state the trend of the data series. For example, having the dataset such as: [5, 7, 8, 11, 17, 3], with you suggestion the trend would state that the OEE has had a negative trend while is clearly a growing trend taking into account the whole dataset.

Comment: Okay, what about finding the differences between each adjacent pair? For your example in the comment it would be [2, 3, 3, 6, -14]. And you check whether there are more positive differences than negative differences?

Comment: How would you qualify the trend for a dataset looking like `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` ?

Answer (score 3):

You could go for a
**sliding average** of the last n values.
Or a
**sliding median** of the last n values.

It highly depends on your application what is appropriate. But both these are very simple to implement and in a lot of cases more than good enough.

Answer (score 0):

As you know from math, one would use d/dt, which more or less is using the step differences.

A trend is should have some weight.

```
class Trend {
    int direction;
    double probability;
}

Trend trend(double[] lastData) {
    double[] deltas = Arrays.copyOf(lastData, lastData.length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < deltas.length; ++i) {
       deltas[i] -= lastData[i + 1];
    }
    // Trend based on two parts:
    int parts = 2;
    int splitN = (deltas.length + 1) / parts;
    int i = 0;
    int[] trends = new int[parts];
    for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; ++j) {
        int n = Math.min(splitN, parts.length - i);
        double partAvg = DoubleStream.of(deltas).skip(i).limit(n).sum() / n;
        trends[j] = tendency(partAvg);
    }
    Trend result = new Trend();
    trend.direction = trends[parts - 1];
    double avg = IntStream.of(trends).average().orElse((double)trend.direction);
    trend.probability = ((direction - avg) + 1) / 2;
    return trends[parts - 1];
}

int tendency(double sum) {
    final double EPS = 0.0001;
    return sum < -EPS ? -1 : sum > EPS ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This is not very sophisticated. For more elaborate treatment a math forum might be useful.

Comment: I need to understand what contains the variable `sums` at line `double sum = DoubleStream.of(sums).skip(i).limit(n).sum() / n;`

Comment: Sorry, `sums` should have been `deltas`. The expression calculatges the average of deltas[i : i+n]